# Check with JavaScript if <p> have no text

Tags: javascript, php, paragraph

I need to put a text in a paragraph but just if is empty.

This is my JavaScript Function that doesn't works:

```
function myFunction(id,name) {
var var1=document.getElementById(id);
if(var1.text==null){
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = name;
}}
```

I have this two paragraphs

```
<p id="1"></p>
<p id="2">Im not Empty</p>
```

Actually with the previous function both paragraphs acquire text but I need to put text in just the first of them.

This is php part, this part works. The problem is just in the JavaScript function.

```
<?php
$idVar=1;
$strVar="I was empty";
while($idVar<=2){
echo "<button onclick='myFunction(".json_encode($idVar).",".json_encode($strVar).")' type='button' id='botones'></button>";
$idVar++;
}
?>
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `var1.value==null` ?

Comment: yes but that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**textContent**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and check if empty with `''` instead of `null`

```
function myFunction(id,name) {
var var1=document.getElementById(id);
if(var1.textContent==''){
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = name;
}}
```

```js
function myFunction(id, name) {
  var var1 = document.getElementById(id);
  console.log(var1.textContent);
  if (var1.textContent == '') {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = name;
  }
}

myFunction(1, 'test');
```

```html
<p id="1"></p>
<p id="2">Im not Empty</p>
```